# Craft CMS - How to include asset fields in PHP entry query?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, orm, craftcms

I am trying to figure out how to return asset field(s) in a PHP entry query. Also if I could learn how to return "custom fields" when returning an Object that would be great too! Right now I am having to specify asArray() to even get access to most of my "custom fields"

As as example: I have a Vehicle Entry which has a custom field with the handle of price (number field) and another custom field (asset field) with the handle of images. When I execute the query without specifying the asArray() param I cannot find the custom fields included in the results. But if I specify asArray() then they are all there with the exception of my images field which I think is because it is an asset field or possible because it can be a collection of images? How can I make sure all the fields tied to an entry are returned in my query?

Here are some examples of queries and the corresponding results:

PHP Query **without asArray():**

```
$entry_query = Entry::find()
->section('inventory')
->all();
```

Returns:
[image]

PHP Query results **with asArray():**

```
$entry_query = Entry::find()
->section('inventory')
->asArray();
```

Returns: 
[image]

However even when specifing to make the result set an array I still cannot figure out how to include the 'images' field.

I am having a difficult time finding an answer via the documentation or an example of someone doing the same. All the examples i find are for the template side in twig.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
    $vehicles = array(); // empty container to hold our modified entries
    // Lets Query our Inventory - all of it
    /** @var array $entry_query   the name of our query to get our inventory - return a list of inventory after we execute query */
    $entries = Entry::find()
        ->section('inventory')
        ->all();

    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        /*
         * Let's get all our custom fields we want
         * to include with our entries
         */
        // Get our image field and add to result set - because it's an asset field this returns a query object
        $ourimages = $entry->images->all(); // get all our images
        $price = $entry->price;
        $featured = $entry->featureThisVehicle;
        $make = $entry->make;
        $model = $entry->model;
        $year = $entry->year;
        $description = $entry->description;
        $inventoryStatus = $entry->inventoryStatus;
        $bodyStyle = $entry->bodyStyle;
        $color = $entry->color;
        $miles = $entry->miles;
        $vin = $entry->vin;
        $stkid = $entry->stkid;

        // cast out entry object as an array - so we can add props to it
        $entry = (array)$entry;

        // add our custom fields to our newly casted entry array
        $entry['images'] = $ourimages;
        $entry['price'] = $price;
        $entry['featured'] = $featured;
        $entry['make'] = $make;
        $entry['model'] = $model;
        $entry['year'] = $year;
        $entry['description'] = $description;
        $entry['inventoryStatus'] = $inventoryStatus;
        $entry['bodyStyle'] = $bodyStyle;
        $entry['color'] = $color;
        $entry['miles'] = $miles;
        $entry['vin'] = $vin;
        $entry['stkid'] = $stkid;

        // Recast back to object just cause (not really necessary since we are json_encode'ing this)
        $entry = (object)$entry;
        array_push($vehicles, $entry);
    }

    return json_encode($vehicles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii has an [array helper function](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array#building-maps) that simplifies this. See this [stack exchange entry](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/how-to-include-asset-fields-in-query-in-php) – it’s essentially the same approach as the one you describe, but simpler (less queries, less lines of code).

Comment: This is a link-only Comment. To need SO guidelines of an Answer, or must be self contained, including the essential pays off the linked page. If the link were to become unavailable, or change its content, this A would become useless, & SO quality would suffer. Also, nobody wants to hop around the web wondering where the real answer lies. Links are GREAT for looking source material & giving credit, & forwarding for supplementary info. But not AS the "answer". That's just link harvesting. It's welcomed, and perfectly fine to put suggestions such as this in the Comments to a post, however.